# Why when change a dictionary from a list of dictionaries, the list also changes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

A code example:

```
>>> y = []
>>> x = {'num':1}
>>> y.append(x)
>>> x['num']=2
>>> x['new_num']=3
>>> y
[{'num': 2, 'new_num': 3}]
```

Why `y` is also changed when I change `x`? Does this logic also exist in other operations in Python?

A list of values don't have this phenomenon:

```
>>> y = []
>>> x = 1
>>> y.append(x)
>>> x += 1
y
[1]
```

Comment: You need to understand what is a reference and what is not, so I'd suggest looking into how primitives versus objects work in Python. Objects use references and primitives do not, which is why your code behaves like it does.

Comment: Here is a decent video explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yv4FrycWRGg

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: In the second example `x += 1` *creates* a new object and assigns its reference to `x`.  The list `y` still refers to the original object.  In the first example `x['num'] = 2` *mutates* the object referred to by `x`.  Since `y` still refers to the original (now mutated) object, it "sees" the change.

Comment: You can also *figure* this out by running your small program here - https://pythontutor.com/

Comment: `y` *hasn't* changed, only its string representation (which is built from the string representation of `x`, which *has* changed since `y` was defined) has.

Comment: I'm about 100% sure this is a duplicate, but don't know how to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you append x to y, y[0] and x still refer to the same object, you can check that by doing:

```
>>> x is y[0]
True
```

You can see that both object share the same memory address.

If you want both to be different you need to do:

```py
y.append(x.copy())
```

Comment: `x is y[0]` is simpler.

Comment: Relying on `id` like this is fragile, because `id(x) == id(y)` can be true as long as the lifetimes of `x` and `y` don't overlap.

Comment: But this only applied when x is a dict? When x is a value this no longer holds

Answer (score 0):

If you know the concept of "Call by value vs call by reference", your question has the same answer. I try to explain the difference between primitive value and reference in your two examples.

At first, you are creating an empty list `[]` and saving its memory address in the variable `y`. After that, you create a dictionary `{'num':1}` and save the memory address of that dictionary in the variable `x`. Then by running the `y.append(x)` statement, you are saving the saved dictionary address from `x` as a new element in the dictionary that is referenced by `y`.

So there is just one dictionary in the memory, but its address is saved in both variable `x` and the first element of the list that is referenced by `y`. Never mind that when you are referencing the dictionary you use the address that is stored in the variable `x` or in the first element of the list, you'll get the same result. So, there is no difference between`x['num']=2` and `y[0]['num']=2` and make the same result.

In your second code, you make a copy of the value `1` stored in the variable `x` as the first value of the list that is referenced by `y`. Copying the value doesn't have any similarity with copying the address, and when you change the `1` value stored in the variable `x` to `2`, it doesn't make any changes in the `1` value that is stored in the first element of the array that is referenced by `y`.